# LaTeX: Align multiple align-environments

Tags: latex, alignment

I would like to align multiple align-environments as e.g.:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
wolf &= animal \iff P(wolf)
\end{align}
blah blah
\begin{align}
a &= b
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

The equal sign of formula (1) and (2) should be aligned with each other, i.e. alignment across several align-environments. Is something like this possible?

Regards,
Stefan

Answer (score 5):

One thing you can do is to use only one align environment, with your interspersed text lines enclosed in a `\textrm{}` command.  The only trouble with this is that the text will not wrap.

A better alternative would be to use an `\intertext{}` command, which handles line breaks without breaking the `\align` alignment, but again, this is meant for small amounts of text.